# Javascript Call Method Confusion

Tags: javascript

Why does this work:

```
this.example = element => {
  console.log(element, element, element);
};

this.example.call({}, 'yo');
//prints yo yo yo
```

As opposed to this:

```
this.example = element => {
  console.log(element, element, element);
};

this.example.call('yo');
/// prints undefined
```

I don't seem to understand why the second example prints undefined.  Why is it necessary to use a parameter (in this case: an empty object), in order for call to print back our desired solution?

Edit:

For those commenting: it seems that 'this' is ignored during ES6 syntax

```
example = element => {
  console.log(element, element, element); // yo yo yo
  console.log(this); // {}
};

function example(element) {
  console.log(element, element, element); // yo yo yo
  console.log(this); // {newObjKey: 'value'}
}

example.call({ newObjKey: 'value' }, 'yo');
```

Comment: First argument of `call()` is the `thisArg` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of the `call` method is the `this` reference the function is bound to. But since it is an arrow function, [the first parameter of `call` is ignored](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Invoked_through_call_or_apply) (however, it is still evaluated!). All the other parameters of the `call` function that follow the `this` reference are passed as function arguments.

In your first example, `{}` is ignored and `"yo"` is passed as a parameter to the `example` function. In your second example, `"yo"` is ignored and you didn't provide a second parameter, so by default it's `undefined`.

Comment: There is no explicit `this` in arrow function but `element` must be second parameter of `call()`. In this case can use anything for first parameter

Comment: @charlietfl Even the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) uses the word _ignored_. (search for `.call(`)

Comment: @charlietfl read my new edit.  Seems AlexR is correct.  Thanks for both of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Call, Apply and Bind methods help to us change **this** (context) inside function.

Firstly you can't use call, apply, bind with arrow function because arrow function don't have context and inside arrow function this value like get lexically like other variables.

Your first example return "yo", "yo", "yo" because call function's first argument change this's (context) value and other arguments pass like arguments.

In your second example return "undefined" 3x time because you change this's value and U don't pass any argument and if U don't pass any argument parameter's value will be undefined.